# All palindrome numbers made from the product of two 3-digit numbers

Tags: c++, palindrome

This program is supposed to print all palindrome numbers formed by the product of two 3-digit numbers, but I don't get that with this program.
What is/are the mistake(s) in the program. Help please.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[100000] = {};
    int b[5];
    int k = 0;
    int temp;
    int sum;
    int rever;
    int r;
    for (int i = 100; i <= 999; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 100; j <= 999; j++)
        {
            a[k] = i * j;
            k++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; a[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        temp = a[i];
        while (temp)
        {
            r = temp % 10;
            temp = temp / 10;
            rever = rever * 10 + r;
        }
        if (rever == a[i])
            cout << a[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here's my 2 cents. Use a debugger, step through your own code! That's the only way you will learn from your mistakes. Also, your loops make no sense, you need to grab an intro to C++ book and learn some basic concepts.

Comment: `a[i] != NULL;`? Do you mean to use `a[i] != 0;`?

Comment: in addition to cleaning up your loops did you consider changing your numbers to strings and then comparing them instead of using a maths approach? palindrome is a character order trait as compared to a mathematical trait.

Comment: @Kam, which of my loops makes no sense? @R Sahu, I meant the loop should run till the value in array a becomes 'null', or 0.

Comment: @Sparsh instead of `a[i] != NULL`, did you consider `i < a.size()` ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop i from 100 to 999, but j from **i** to 999 cause 231*952 is the same as 952*231. Using a string is also easier.

In C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char ch[7], k, l;
    for (int i = 100; i < 1000; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < 1000; j++) {
            sprintf(ch, "%d", i*j);
            l=strlen(ch)-1;
            k=0;
            while(ch[k++]==ch[l--]) {
                    if (k>=l) {
                            printf("%d*%d=%s\n", i,j,ch);
                            break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, your formatting is obnoxiously inconsistent. Indent that all uniformly, and it'll be much easier to help.

The test on your second `i` loop is pretty clearly wrong. How many times should it run, and what should its stopping condition be? How many values does it have to test from `a`?

Answer (score 0):

Errors I see in your code:

1. Size of `a`. You have declared

   ```
   int a[100000] = {};
   ```

   However, you are trying to set values of  `900 x 900` = `810,000` elements in it. That should be

   ```
   int a[SIZE] = {};
   ```

   where `SIZE` is `810,000` or higher.
2. Use of `a[i] != NULL` in the `for` statement is not right. You should use:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
   ```
3. In the `for` loop where you are checking whether a number is a palindrome, `rever` is never reset. Furthermore, `rever` is not initialized before it is used.
4. The line where you print the palindrome numbers needs a newline added to the output. Otherwise, all the numbers will come out as a very long string of digits.

Here's an updated version with the fixes:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const int SIZE = 810000;
   int a[SIZE] = {};
   int b[5];
   int k = 0;
   int temp;
   int sum;
   int r;
   for (int i = 100; i <= 999; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 100; j <= 999; j++)
      {
         a[k] =  i * j;
         k++;
      }
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
   {
      temp = a[i];
      int rever = 0;
      while (temp)
      {
         r =  temp % 10;
         temp = temp/10;
         rever = rever * 10 + r;
      }
      if (rever == a[i])
         cout << a[i] << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. But even this code doesn't work. I'm using codeblocks and on running this programme it say "palindrome.exe has stopped working".

Comment: @Sparsh, don't know how to help you there. It works on my desktop. It also works at http://ideone.com/3blZU4.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for 2 for loops and so many variables and a long array you made.
Also your second for loop termination condition is not correct.

```
for(i=0;a[i]!=NULL;i++)
```

we know that there are only 900 3 digit numbers so we can terminate loop at 900 x 900 ie 810000

```
for(i=0;i<810000;i++)
```

Solution to problem statement. I found a lot of errors so i coded it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

int i,j;
long int number, reverse,temp;
for (i = 100; i <= 999; i++)
{
    for (j = 100; j <= 999; j++)
    {

        number = i*j;
        temp = number;
        reverse = 0;
        for (; temp != 0;)
        {
            reverse = reverse * 10;
            reverse = reverse + temp % 10;
            temp = temp / 10;
        }
        if (reverse == number)
            cout << number<<endl;


    }
}

_getch();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: @Sparsh An upvote and answer acceptance would make my day. Glad I can help. :)